# Using ArcGIS, can data relationships be created between separate geodatabase containers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, relationship-class

I have several ESRI geodatabases that contain specific detailed information around a central theme.  Without revealing the specifics about the theme, each geodatabase has its own domain-driven subtypes and value tables, but there appears to be no attribute connection between geodatabases.  Presuming a relationship - *other than geospatial* - can be surmised between databases, how would this relationship be created?  I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: In order to build relationships in ArcGIS, you need 2 things.  First, you need spatial data.  Second, you need attribute data with some link to the spatial data.  If you want to build relationships between pure attribute data, you need to have at the very least, a common Unique ID.  If you don't have this, you don't have a relationship between data.  If you don't have a common ID link, the most you can do is link tables from each DB to spatial data, and see if there is a spatial overlay relationship.  If this explanation is not on the right track, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Relationship class can be created for objects within the same file geodatabase only. If you store your data in multiple geodatabases (Shops table in one, and ShopDetails table in another), you could use ArcMap map document to use the Relate to get those tables connected; this will let you work with the data visually within your ArcMap session (only within this .mxd though).

[ArcGIS Help page: Relating the attributes in one table to another](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s0000002v000000)